# Can anyone help out with this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$t^2x''-(6t^4+2t)x'+9t^6x=0$$

I don't have an effective (I don't know how to solve these types) way of solving it, because the technique used in class was unclear to me. I would very much appreciate an answer on this. Thanks in advance.
 and$$xx''+2x^2x'^2+x'^2=2xx'/t,x(1)=1,x'(1)=3.$$

Comment: Ask a second question in a different post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=t^3$, hence we get

$$z^{2/3}x''(t)-(6z^{4/3}+2z^{1/3})x'(t)+9z^2x=0                           (*)$$
From Chain rule, we obtain
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dt}\cdot\frac{dx(z)}{dz}$$ and
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx(z)}{dz}\cdot\frac{dz}{dt}\right)=\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}\cdot\frac{dx(z)}{dz}+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2\cdot\frac{d^2x(z)}{dz^2}$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=3z^{2/3}\frac{dx(z)}{dz}$$ and
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=9z^{4/3}\frac{d^2x(z)}{dz^2}+6z^{1/3}\frac{dx(z)}{dz}$$

Putting this 2 identities into (*), we'll obtain
$$9z^2\frac{d^2x(z)}{dz^2}-18z^2\frac{dx(z)}{dz}+9z^2x(z)=0$$
so
$$x''(z)-18x'(z)+9x(z)=0$$

which has a general solution
$x(z) = c_1e^z + c_2e^zz$,
and if we sub back $z = t^3$, we'll get
$$x(t) = c_1e^{t^3} + c_2e^{t^3}t^3$$ 
as the final general solution of (*).

Comment: Can you please help with second?

Comment: As a continuation of your answer?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: I have no idea for the 2nd question as well, you might want to ask that in a different post.